# How to select a dropdown option using playwright in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webautomation, playwright

I would like to select "All" option from the below DOM using Playwright JS, and I have tried `page.selectOption('select#rows per page', '-1');` and `page.selectOption('id=mui-55656', '-1');` to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. [image]

Comment: You were so close with both of your attempts.  This would have worked: `page.selectOption('#mui-55656', '-1');` However, I am suspicious of that potentially being a dynamically created `id`. If you are certain there are no other `[aria-label="rows per page"]` attributed elements on the page, the answer below will be sufficient.

Comment: The `#` in the select is shorthand for selecting by `id`.  `page.selectOption('select[aria-label="rows per page"]', '-1');` would have also worked. Or, `page.selectOption('select#mui-55656', '-1');`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to select the option using the `aria-label`

```
await page.selectOption('[aria-label="rows per page"]', '-1');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also for adding those extra tags 

So the above line works in selecting the first one, value=5. Is there a way to select value=-1 option ?

Comment: @GBackMania I misunderstood the "all" part. Answer updated.

Comment: Aha! That works. Thank you 

Now, out of curiosity, is there a way to access using "id" attribute? If yes, would that be considered best practice?

Comment: @GBackMania yes! it's a CSS selector. You can try '#mui-55656'

Answer (score 0):

use css mode :
`await page.selectOption('#mui-55656', '-1');`